# Как найти статью по ссылке в базе данных yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь реализовать блог на yii2. Как правильно организовать поиск статьи на сайте в базе данных после перехода по url
Предположим у нас есть url http://domen.me/post/udachnyytest

поиск в базе данных происходит по url udachnyytest?

Comment: Обычный запрос `SELECT`

Comment: Это понятно, а поиск самой статьи всегда происходит по url статьи или по id?

Comment: Ну это уж как Вы сделаете, можно в url и id передавать, и как у Вас алиас

Comment: А можно ли искать по id а в urlе передавать domen.ru/udachnyytest

Comment: Ищите по `udachnyytest`. `domen.ru/45` - ищите по `id`

Comment: у вас модельки отвалились. и советую перейти в продакшн режим

Comment: Просто почистил базу, удалил тестовый урл. В любом случае, спасибо за сообщение.